# What's the name of this field?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, nlp

Image an application that accepts human text as input data, application process the text and then user ask a question from application, finaly application answers the question according to input data.

What's the name of the above field in AI?

Is there any open source project that implements first paragraph?

For example:

```
User> My name is Amir.
Machine> OK.
User> What's my name?
Machine> Your name is Amir.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's [natural language processing](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Natural_language_processing) (NLP), more specifically a combination of [question answering](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Question_answering) and dialogue systems/[chatterbots](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Chatterbot).

If you google those terms + "open source", you'll find lots of stuff, but don't expect anything to work magic out of the box. Better pick up a book on the topic first; the classic is [Jurafsky & Martin](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~martin/slp.html).

Answer (score 1):

> "Is there any open source project that implements..."

We have to mention [A.L.I.C.E.](http://alice.pandorabots.com/) here as an **award-winning** free natural language artificial intelligence chat robot and it is [open-source](http://www.alicebot.org/downloads/) free software.